# Eliminate extra rows that intersect

Tags: sql-server, duplication

I have a table of geometry values where some rows intersect other rows.

I need a list of rows where the geometry overlaps other rows, but I'd like the list to be as concise as possible.

Here's the setup:

```
USE tempdb;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.t;

CREATE TABLE dbo.t
(
    n varchar(100) NOT NULL
    , i geometry NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.t (n, i)
VALUES ('poly1', geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((1 2, 1 4, 1 5, 4 6, 1 2))', 4326))
     , ('poly2', geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((1 2, 1 3, 2 5, 4 6, 1 2))', 4326))
     , ('poly3', geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((7 9, 8 7, 9 6, 7 9))', 4326))

SELECT t1.n
    , t2.n
FROM dbo.t t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.t t2 ON t1.i.STIntersects(t2.i) = 1
WHERE 
    t1.n <> t2.n;
```

The output looks like:

| n | n |
| --- | --- |
| poly2 | poly1 |
| poly1 | poly2 |

However, I'd like only a single row for brevity.  i.e. because poly1 overlaps poly2 *and* poly2 overlaps poly1 I'm getting two rows returned where I'd like only one, as in:

| n | n |
| --- | --- |
| poly1 | poly2 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you need an < or > instead of a <>.

That is similar to when you try to find dupes in your data

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dbo.t
> (
>     n varchar(100) NOT NULL
>     , i geometry NOT NULL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO dbo.t (n, i)
> VALUES ('poly1', geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((1 2, 1 4, 1 5, 4 6, 1 2))', 4326))
>      , ('poly2', geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((1 2, 1 3, 2 5, 4 6, 1 2))', 4326))
>      , ('poly3', geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((7 9, 8 7, 9 6, 7 9))', 4326))
>
> SELECT t1.n
>     , t2.n
> FROM dbo.t t1
>     INNER JOIN dbo.t t2 ON t1.i.STIntersects(t2.i) = 1
> WHERE 
>     t1.n < t2.n;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> n     | n    
> :---- | :----
> poly1 | poly2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f6a5eecbe2f38974680e3bc46df50c9)*